# Display all upcoming items and not past items with Javascript and XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, if-statement

I have an interactive map that displays dates of events in different regions of the United States. The map works great parsing the XML document and getting the data and actually displaying it. However my issue is I cannot get items from 2014 to display. The map pulls data from the XML document and checks it against the current month/day/year. If the data equals today or later it displays it. But it is not showing any data from 2014.

Here is my conditional statement checking the dates against each other -- this is where the problem lies:

```
if (Number(currentYear) <= findCourseYear || Number(currentYear) <= findCourseYear2){

    if (Number(currentYear) <= findCourseYear && Number(currentMonth) + 1 <= findCourseMonth || Number(currentYear) <= findCourseYear2 && Number(currentMonth) + 1 <= findCourseMonth2){

            if (Number(currentMonth) + 1 == findCourseMonth && Number(currentDay) <= findCourseDay || Number(currentMonth) + 1 < findCourseMonth || Number(currentMonth) + 1 == findCourseMonth2 && Number(currentDay) <= findCourseDay2 || Number(currentMonth) + 1 < findCourseMonth2){

                courseType.push($(this).find('type').text());
                courseName.push($(this).find('name').text());
                courseCity.push($(this).find('city').text());
                courseState.push($(this).find('state').text());
                courseDate.push($(this).find('date').text());
                courseLink.push($(this).find('link').text());
                courseGeo.push($(this).find('geo').text());
             }
     }
}
```

What in this conditional is preventing the map from displaying data from next year?

NOTE: The years are entered as 2 digits. EX: 10/22/13 or 5/10/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript's `Date()` constructor. Looks like your check could be simplified to:

```
var now = Date.now();
var courseDate1 = new Date("20" + findCourseYear, +findCourseMonth - 1, findCourseDay);
var courseDate2 = new Date("20" + findCourseYear2, +findCourseMonth2 - 1, findCourseDay2);
if (courseDate1 >= now || courseDate2 >= now) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thats what the `currentDate` variable is: `var currentDate = new Date();`

Comment: Then why don't you turn your course dates into `Date` objects as I showed? Makes it a lot simpler than comparing the individual years, months and days. You can just compare the `Date`s themselves with a `>=` operator. Your conditionals are very confusing, so your bug is hard to pinpoint. Simplify the conditionals by just comparing `Date` objects.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log([findCourseYear, findCourseMonth, findCourseDay, findCourseYear2, findCourseMonth2, findCourseDay2].join(" "));`

Comment: Sure, there are a TON of values in there, but here is one output: `13 10 9 13 10 11 ` Year, Month, Day

Comment: Ah, change the date constructors to be like `new Date("20" + findCourseYear, findCourseMonth, findCourseDay);`

Edit: sorry, you also need to subtract 1 from the month. So `new Date("20" + findCourseYear, +findCourseMonth - 1, findCourseDay);`

Comment: Now it's showing all dates, including the past ones... Closer though!

Comment: I got it working. I had to add a `-1` to the `findCourseMonth` variables. Thanks!